# ADF support for scanadf on HP scanner

Tags: hardware, driver, peripherals

I have installed SANE and I'm trying to scan pages with the ADF (automatic document feeder) of my HP ScanJet 8250. I found [scanadf](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scanadf), but it does not use the ADF for scanning. I now read at the end of the page

> **sane-hp** - Hewlett Packard scanners. A patch to the sane-hp backend is necessary. The `--scantype=ADF` option must be specified (earlier versions of the backend used the `--scan-from-adf` option, instead).

Now, what is the sane-hp backend and where do I apply that option?

Comment: But are you sure sane-hp supports ScanJet 8000, because it is not in the support list: : https://linux.die.net/man/5/sane-hp

Comment: @tlfong01: hmm, at least SANE scans from the non-ADF.

Comment: I see.  If SANE supports 8200 non-ADF, then there is hope to do ADF.  I have never used ADF before, so I am afraid I am not knowledgeable enough to help. PS - I don't know what is "backend" either.  Perhaps I can google a bit.

Comment: I googled and found the following comment: "Essentially, saned on the server and the net backend on the client are used to convert a non-networked or network-incapable scanner into a networked one" -  https://wiki.debian.org/SaneOverNetwork.  My wild guess is that the "backend" is a piece of software to patch at the printer, but only 10% sure. I have little idea what is going on. So I can only wish you good luck. Cheers

Comment: @tlfong01: Thanks. I'll also continue trying.

Comment: Hi @Thomas Weller, "Backend" just means "driver":  (1) SANE: Backends (Drivers)
http://www.sane-project.org/sane-backends.html

(2) SANE - Frontends (Applications)
http://www.sane-project.org/sane-frontends.html

(3） Bug 1392712 - Bug in sane-backend preventing scanning from hp scanjet 8200：
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1392712

(4) Backend configuration file 
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/sane-hp.5.html

(5) ADF Exercise Test
https://support.hp.com/au-en/document/c00022537

(6) Linux Scanner How To
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Scanner-HOWTO/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I don't need `scanadf`. I can scan from ADF using `scanimage`:

```
sudo scanimage --source "ADF duplex"
```

That might be a specific option for the HP 8200 series.

Unfortunately, I always get a segmentation fault for the second page.